# What are the ramifications of long open sessions?

Tags: sql-server, session, dm-exec-sessions

I'm looking after a SQL server having long open sessions.

There is no open transaction, or actively running query (requests) for this session.

1. What is the reason why a session may remain open? Is it because a transaction is opened and not closed?
2. What are the ramifications of having such an open session?

Answer (score 7):

> 1. What is the reason why a session may remain open?

[Connection Pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling).

> Is it because a transaction is opened and not closed?

> There is no open transaction, or actively running query (requests) for this session.

You said yourself there isn't an open transaction. Of course if there was one, the session would still need to be open too.

> What are the ramifications of having such an open session?

Not many if the session isn't actually doing anything. The only one I can think of is there's a [limit to how many connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-user-connections-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16) the server allows at one time of 32,767 user connections. If for some reason you were at that limit (unlikely) then a new user connection wouldn't be able to be established.

Comment: "If for some reason you were at that limit (unlikely) then a new user connection wouldn't be able to be established." And even less likely if the connections are being pooled, since that usually comes with its own client-side connection limits. (Though I suppose not necessarily.)